# Date of Sentinel 2 web-service in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, sentinel-2, web-service, living-atlas

I am using Sentinel 2 imagery as a web service (layer) in ArcGIS Pro. The layer is [Sentinel-2 Views](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd61b9e0c69c4e14bebd50a9a968348c) from the ESRI Living Atlas. This loads and displays fine, however the default currency (date) of the images in this web service vary considerably (e.g. some images go back to 2015).

The [ESRI Sentinel Explorer](https://sentinel2explorer.esri.com) web application also allows viewing of Sentinel 2 data. However, the web service (layer) here seems to contain images which are much more recent. While I am not certain, I believe the web service is the same as the one in ArcGIS Pro. More detailed information about the Sentinel Explorer App can be found here.

Does anyone know how to ensure that the [Sentinel-2 Views](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd61b9e0c69c4e14bebd50a9a968348c) layer in ArcGIS Pro defaults to the more current imagery (% cloud cover is a factor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date (currency) of the image can be managed by setting a 'definition query' in the layer properties. If you're using the [Sentinel-2 Views](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd61b9e0c69c4e14bebd50a9a968348c) layer then apply the definition query to the  'acquisitiondate' field. I found this easier to do using an SQL query than the default query builder. A sample is shown below to find image between the following dates, note the timestamp format is 'dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss'

"acquisitiondate >= timestamp '1-11-21 0:0:0' And acquisitiondate <= timestamp '10-11-21 0:0:0'"

Notes:

- I am not sure how it selects a specific date/image within the date range provided. A Sentinel 2 satellite returns to the same location approx every 5 days, so keep this in mind when setting date ranges i.e. keep the range fairly narrow (10 days).
- According the description on the website the [Sentinel-2 Views](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd61b9e0c69c4e14bebd50a9a968348c) layer "is designed to include imagery collected within the past 14 months". So searching earlier than this is not likely to work.

[image: Layer Properties - Definition Query]